# Are there any free Team Foundation Servers we can host projects on?

Tags: tfs, hosting

are there any free Team Foundation Server sites we can use for our *private* development? Please don't say CodePlex (which I love) because that means the code is all opensource.

Lastly, I also understand that some people might raise the issue of having their private code hosted somewhere by people they do not know, etc.. so please don't raise any security concerns.

I'm guessing there are no free services because of licensing reasons?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Microsoft are currently providing their next generation cloud hosted TFS service at [tfs.visualstudiow.com](http://tfspreview.com) - private repositories are free for up to 5 users but they have indicated that they will be charging for the service when you in the future when you have more than 5 users in your account.

If you are a small start-up and wanted to use TFS inside your firewall, then take a look at the new [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) program from Microsoft.  This provides basically everything you need to start up a Microsoft technology based company for free (apart from the hardware) - including TFS and Visual Studio.

Comment: I must respectfully disagree; Dynamsoft does it for up to 3 devs for free.  See my post below.

Comment: Actually, see Catherine's post, she said it before me, doh!

Comment: True, but read my reply, to Catherine's post.

Comment: Was it deleted?  I don't see a post from a Catherine or anything about Dynamsoft

Comment: @Pickle Pumper, no post from Catherine

Comment: This link shows that they are no more offering free services: http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/SAWHosted_Plan.aspx

Comment: Is this stil exist on the year? I cannot login since TFS merge with Azure DevOps Server –

Answer (score 6):

I would find it doubtful that there would be a free one.  Team Foundation Server was very expensive for us to implement so I would be surprised if someone was hosting for free.  Other than the CodePlex type options.

There are services where you can pay per user per month like  [this one](http://www.phase2.com/hosted_team_foundation_server_overview2.aspx) or [this one](http://www.teamdevcentral.com/pricing.html)>

I find it doubtful you will find free though.

Answer (score 3):

None are free, but there are four TFS hosting options discussed in this [Simple Talk article](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1315), covering:

- PRAKTIK Hosting
- TeamDevCentral
- SaaS Made Easy
- DiscountASP

Microsoft's own TFSPreview is now rebranded as [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information/), which is free for up to 5 users.

Answer (score 1):

We're running a pilot program on our TFS Hosting services, so for a short period of time it's free. After that we'll have the best prices on the full TFS suite.

http://www.tfsserver.com

Comment: It's not free, but I haven't had any problems with at work during the last 1½ year